# Proofs by contradiction, if P then Q, what if Q is equivalent to A and B?

Tags: logic, solution-verification

Say we have a proposition If P then Q, and let Q = A $\land$ B

If we do a proof by contradiction, we assume the negation of Q: $\lnot (A \land B) =  \lnot A \lor \lnot B$

From here, can we continue our contradiction proof by starting with only $\lnot A$ or $\lnot B$? Or do we have to look at them both?

My intuition tells me we have to look at both, and on that line of thinking, can we say $P \Rightarrow A \land B$ is equivalent to $P \Rightarrow A \land P \Rightarrow B$, and therefore we have to look at both negations?

But the statement $\lnot A \lor \lnot B$ makes me think we need only look at one...

Sorry this is basic, I am just getting back into math...

Comment: Well if you assume $\lnot A$ and get a contradiction you are not done as it's perfectly possible for $A$ to be true (so long as $B$ is false). So you have to prove that $\lnot B$ also gives a contradiction.  (In other words the only thing that won't give a contradiction is $A$ and $B$ both being true).

Comment: You may prove $(\neg A\vee\neg B)\to\neg P$ using a Proof by Cases.  Assume $\neg A$ and derive $\neg P$, **and** assume $\neg B$ and derive $\neg P$ also.$$(\neg A\to\neg P)\wedge(\neg B\to\neg P)~~\iff~~(\neg A\vee\neg B)\to\neg P\\(P\to A)\wedge(P\to B)~~\iff~~P\to(A\wedge B)$$

Answer (score 1):

To do a contrapositive proof of $P \implies (A\land B)$ you must prove $(\lnot A \lor \lnot B) \implies \lnot P$ or in other words and assuming $(\lnot A\lor \lnot B)$ causes a contradiction to $P$.

In essence $\lnot A \lor \lnot B$ is *still* a simple $M \lor N$ statements with $M = \lnot A$ and $N =\lnot B$.  It doesn't matter if the components are negations or postive, they are are still components.  You are still trying to prove:  $something$ or $somethingelse$ implies $a third thing$.

And remember how to do an OR prove.

$M \lor N \implies W$.

You must show, separately, that $M \implies W$.  (If $M$ is true but $W$ is not, then $M\lor N$ is true but $W$ is not so $M\lor N\implies W$ is not true.)

But that alone is not enough.  We could have $M$ but false but $M\lor N$ is true if $N$ is true and then we must have $W$ true but we didn't do anything about that case when we only considered $M$ being true.

So we must consider $M$ being true implies $W$ is true.  As well as showing $N$ being true implies $W$ is true.

But they don't have to *both* be true *always* at the same time.  We can have $M$ is false but $N$ true (and still $W$) or $M$ is true but $N$ is falswe (and still $W$).

.....

ANd that's an OR proof in general.  Even if $M = \lnot A$ and $N =\lnot B$ and $W = \lnot P$ it's still the same.

Answer (score 0):

You need to show that $\neg A \lor \neg B$ implies a contradiction. So, showing that $\neg A$ by itself implies a contradiction is not enough, since $\neg A$ is not implied by $\neg A \lor \neg B$.

So, you need to show that *each* of $\neg A$ and $\neg B$ lead to a contradiction.

Then you would have $\neg A \to \bot$ as well as $\neg B \to \bot$, which means that you have $(\neg A \to \bot) \land (\neg B \to \bot)$, which is equivalent to $(\neg A \lor \neg B) \to \bot$, which is what you need to show.

This makes sense from the following perspective as well:  Typically, with a goal like $A \land B$, you would show *two* things: that $A$ is implied by premise $P$, and that $B$ is also implied by premise $P$.  Now, to show that $A$ is implied by $P$, you can do a proof by contradiction: show that $\neg A$ leads to a contradiction.  But clearly you then still need to prove $B$ as well ... and for that you could do its own proof by contradiction. So again, you need *both*.

Let me also point out that approaching the problem from the latter perspective (proving $A$ and $B$ separately) is really just the best way to approach this, because you may find that, for example, proving $A$ might work well using a proof by contradiction, but for proving $B$, a direct approach might work a lot better. So, this way you keep your options open. But if you assume the negation of the conclusion $Q$, you basically lock yourself into doing a proof by contradiction for both.

Comment: Thanks! Your breakdown of the statements on the third line definitely helps.

Comment: I thing the phrase "both $\lnot A$ and $\lnot B$ lead to a contradiction" leads to confusion for students.  The student may interpret it as [$\lnot A$ and $\lnot B$] must both be true at the same time to lead to a contradiction; whereas what you actually mean is that *each* $\lnot A$ and $\lnot B$ will each lead to contradictions-- (i.e. it's not enough that one does and the other doesn't; or that the both together do; -- it must be that each one by itself does, and the other one, by itself does.)

Comment: @fleablood Good suggestion, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may prove $(\neg A\vee\neg B)\to\neg P$ using a Proof by Cases.  Assume $\neg A$ and derive $\neg P$, **and** assume $\neg B$ and derive $\neg P$ also.$$(\neg A\to\neg P)\wedge(\neg B\to\neg P)~~\iff~~(\neg A\vee\neg B)\to\neg P\\~\\(P\to A)\wedge(P\to B)~~\iff~~P\to(A\wedge B)$$

> But the statement $¬A∨¬B$ makes me think we need only look at one...

You wish to show that having *at least one* from not-$A$ or not-$B$ is sufficient to have not-$P$.

If you do prove that having not-$A$ alone is sufficient, that does not prove that having not-$B$ alone is also sufficient.

You have to prove having *each* alone will suffice before you can say that having *at least one* will suffice.